# display all 4 options each time in the select menu

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash. I want to have a select menu in bash. It has four options. Here is the code:

```
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Option 4")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            ;;
        "Exit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

When I execute this code, the first time full menu with 4 options appears, but later times (2nd, 3rd and ... times) only "Please enter your choice:" appears. I want each time all 4 options appear like the first time.

As another problem, I want each time that the program is executed and 4 options are re-appeared, the previous commands and terminal content to be cleared. I did this by putting a "clear" before:

```
select opt in "${options[@]}"
```

but this way only the first time the terminal content was cleared.

What can I do to solve these problems?

Comment: How are you expecting for the user to read the message and then clear the screen? I guess you would like to add some kind of pause asking user to enter any key to continue. If not the message being displayed would be barely readable due to the little time it is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add a new loop that embeds your menu and then add another `break` to each case, and for option 4 edit to `break 2` as shown in code below. I also added the option to clear the screen after an option is selected.

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
while true; do
    clear
    options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Exit")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            "Option 1")
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                break
                ;;
            "Option 2")
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                break
                ;;
            "Option 3")
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                break
                ;;
            "Exit")
                break 2
                ;;
            *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
        esac
    done
done
```

So a case of use of this code would be:

```
$ ./select.sh
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Exit
Please enter your choice: 1
you chose choice 1 which is Option 1
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Exit
Please enter your choice: 2
you chose choice 2 which is Option 2
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Exit
Please enter your choice: 3
you chose choice 3 which is Option 3
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Exit
Please enter your choice: 4

$
```

### Adding a pause after selection

In case you want to ensure that the user can read the option selected you can add the following line before the last `done` of the code:

```
read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
```

That way the user will see the message and will have to press the Enter key to get the menu shown again.

And a case of use of this would be:

```
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Exit
Please enter your choice: 1
you chose choice 1 which is Option 1
Press [Enter] key to continue...
```

Comment: Using your code, in case option 4 is "exit", my program will never stop and re-displays the menu over and over

Comment: @Pablo Please try the code. The `break 2` will actually make the program to exit. Indeed `Option 4` would be the option to exit as I guessed you were expecting to be.

Comment: In the first case of use I posted you can see how `Option 4` exists the program. Maybe `Option 4` should be named as `Exit` for future reference for other people reading this post.

Comment: Changed the code in my answer just to reflect which one is the Exit option.

Comment: I changed option 4 to exit.

Answer (score 1):

If the user hits enter without making *any* selection, the menu will be redisplayed. As far as I know, the only way to programmatically force the menu to be drawn again would be to wrap the `select` statement in another loop, and re-execute the `select` statement. You'll use `break` to exit the `select` and return to the top of the wrapper loop, and `break 2` to exit from both the `select` and the wrapper.

```
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Option 4")
while :; do
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            ;;
        "Find Subdomain")
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            ;;
        "Option 4")
            break 2
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
    break
  done
done
```

Comment: This code I believe doesn't work as expected by OP. It only shows again the menu when selecting an invalid option.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the question closely enough. It's sufficient to move the `break` to after the `case` statement, rather than only breaking from the default case.